# Xcode issue importing header file

Tags: ios, xcode

I've an iOS project, with cocoapods for external libraries management.
When I try to import an header file from that, instead of the right library, Xcode imports the file (with the same name) from another project/folder.
Furthermore the file is different.
If I want to reference to the right header I must write the absolute path

```
#import "Pods/CHCSVParser/CHCSVParser/CHCSVParser.h"
```

Why?

Comment: If this is an external library, shouldn't you be doing #import <file.h> instead of #import "file.h"?

Comment: Even with #import<file.h> Xcode imports the wrong library.

Comment: Hmm... hard to say without looking at the library imports and your project settings.

Comment: @tommy- import them in Prefix.pch if u r using cocoapods

Comment: If you set up CocoaPods correctly, then all you need to do is to `#import "CHSVparser.h"`.

Comment: did you try `#import <CHCSVParser/CHCSVParser.h>`